# List of complex datasets for ML in the cloud comparison

Tags: machine-learning

I'm looking for *complex* datasets for performing a comparison on machine learning in the cloud solutions such as Amazon Machine Learning, Microsoft Azure, IBM Watson, Google Prediction API, Rapid Miner and some others.

In particular I will try the **blackbox** prediction (and/or classification) capabilities offered by some of these systems, and compare it with state of the art results. SaaS such as Google Prediction API say they can pick the *best* algorithm for our problem; I'm analyzing how well do they perform in order to compare them with the closeness to state of the art results and some other further analysis.

It's hard to define *complexity* for this case, however I'm looking for datasets that have available results for at least 3 different algorithms, and where at least 1 has shown considerably bad performance (e.g. accuracy or error) in comparison with the best one. Size of the dataset will not be an issue. Following this idea *complex* would mean that there exists bad performing typical approaches that are considerably worst performing than the best solution.

Where should I look for that can have multiple algorithm results both well and bad performing? Any datasets recommendations?

PS: Naturally I would need datasets for supervised learning.

Comment: Have a look at http://kaggle.com/ - or MNIST, IRIS, Pascal VOC, ...

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation @moose I know Kaggle and the mentioned datasets, however the idea of the question is asking if someone know specific datasets that fit the characteristics I described. I would take a further look into Kaggle past competitions though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this great tour-de-force [study](http://jmlr.csail.mit.edu/papers/volume15/delgado14a/delgado14a.pdf) by Manuel Fernandez-Delgado at JMLR. They ran lots of classifiers against plenty of data sets from UCI. I believe you will find everything you need. hth